# 800+ open connections being caused by SharePoint 2013 crawl?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, search, sql

All are "sleeping". Everything seems to be working fine but need to figure out why there are so many open connections. Any ideas?

> CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.proc_MSS_GetNextCrawlBatch  @ComponentID int, 
>   @CrawlID int,  @BatchSize int,  @MaxTransactionsPerHost int,  @BatchID
>   bigint OUTPUT  AS  DECLARE @ITEMTYPE_INVALIDLINK tinyint SET
>   @ITEMTYPE_INVALIDLINK = 0 DECLARE @ITEMTYPE_STARTADDRESS tinyint SET
>   @ITEMTYPE_STARTADDRESS = 1 DECLARE @ITEMTYPE_LINK tinyint SET
>   @ITEMTYPE_LINK = 2 DECLARE @ITEMTYPE_LINK_CHANGELOG tinyint SET
>   @ITEMTYPE_LINK_CHANGELOG = 4 DECLARE @ITEMTYPE_LINK_EXCLUDED tinyint
>   SET @ITEMTYPE_LINK_EXCLUDED = 5 DECLARE @ITEMTYPE_LASTLINK tinyint SET
>   @ITEMTYPE_LASTLINK = 7 DECLARE @ITEMTYPE_LINK_DISCOVERED tinyint SET
>   @ITEMTYPE_LINK_DISCOVERED = 8  DECLARE @STATUS_OK int SET @STATUS_OK =
>   1 DECLARE @STATUS_NOTINITIALIZED int SET @STATUS_NOTINITIALIZED = 0
>   DECLARE @STATUS_DISABLED int SET @STATUS_DISABLED = 3 DECLARE
>   @STATUS_REMOUNT int SET @STATUS_REMOUNT = 4 DECLARE @STATUS_INACTIVE
>   int SET @STATUS_INACTIVE= 5 DECLARE @STATUS_DISABLED_FOR_REMOVE int
>   SET @STATUS_DISABLED_FOR_REMOVE = 6  DECLARE
>   @MINI_HIGH_PRIORITY_CRAWL_ID int SET @MINI_HIGH_PRIORITY_CRAWL_ID = 1
>   DECLARE @MINI_LOW_PRIORITY_CRAWL_ID int SET
>   @MINI_LOW_PRIORITY_CRAWL_ID = 2  SET NOCOUNT ON  --SET XACT_ABORT ON -
>   no need to set XACT_ABORT ON because the transaction is now driven by
>   C++ code  DECLARE @Status int  SELECT @Status = Status FROM
>   MSSCrawlComponentsLocal WITH(HOLDLOCK) WHERE ComponentID =
>   @ComponentID  IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0 OR @Status = @STATUS_DISABLED  BEGIN
>   RAISERROR          (N'The component ID %d is disabled',          16,
>   -- Severity.          1, -- State.          @ComponentID)      RETURN 0  END  --this exclusive lock prevents 2 crawl components to load
>   transactions from the queue concurently  INSERT INTO MSSBatchHistory
>   WITH(TABLOCKX)(CrawlID) VALUES (@CrawlID)   SELECT @BatchID =
>   @@IDENTITY  DECLARE @RowsSelected int  SET @RowsSelected = 0  DECLARE
>   @HostsInCrawl int  SELECT @HostsInCrawl = COUNT(*) FROM
>   MSSCrawlHostsLog WITH(NOLOCK) WHERE CrawlID = @CrawlID  IF
>   @HostsInCrawl > 1  BEGIN      DECLARE @DocsInQueue int = 0      SELECT
>   @DocsInQueue = COUNT(*) FROM MSSCrawlQueue WITH(NOLOCK) WHERE CrawlID
>   = @CrawlID      IF @DocsInQueue < 1000000 OR @CrawlID IN(@MINI_HIGH_PRIORITY_CRAWL_ID, @MINI_LOW_PRIORITY_CRAWL_ID)
>   BEGIN          CREATE TABLE #HostsInQueue (HostID int, DocCount int)
>   INSERT INTO #HostsInQueue (HostID, DocCount)          SELECT TOP 10
>   HostID, COUNT(*) as C          FROM TVF_MSSCrawlQueue_CrawlID_Nolock
>   (@CrawlID)          WHERE BatchID != 0               AND ComponentID =
>   @ComponentID          GROUP BY HostID          ORDER BY C DESC
>   DELETE #HostsInQueue WHERE DocCount < @MaxTransactionsPerHost
>   UPDATE _CrawlQueue           SET BatchID = @BatchID, ComponentID =
>   @ComponentID           FROM           (              SELECT TOP
>   (@BatchSize) SeqID              FROM
>   TVF_MSSCrawlQueue_CrawlID_BatchID(@CrawlID, 0) _CrawlQueue_Tmp
>   OUTER APPLY TVF_MSSCrawlQueue_DocID_ComponentID(_CrawlQueue_Tmp.DocID,
>   @ComponentID) AS _CrawlQueue_DocID              --CROSS APPLY
>   TVF_MSSCrawlURL_DocID (_CrawlQueue_Tmp.DocID) _CrawlURL
>   WHERE _CrawlQueue_Tmp.HostID NOT IN (SELECT HostID FROM #HostsInQueue)
>   AND _CrawlQueue_DocID.DocID IS NULL                  --AND
>   _CrawlURL.DocID = xxxx              ORDER BY SeqID          ) AS _CrawlQueue_Top          CROSS APPLY          TVF_MSSCrawlQueue_SeqID(_CrawlQueue_Top.SeqID) AS _CrawlQueue
>   OPTION(FORCE ORDER, MAXDOP 1)          SELECT @RowsSelected =
>   @@ROWCOUNT      END  END  IF @RowsSelected < @BatchSize  BEGIN
>   UPDATE _CrawlQueue       SET BatchID = @BatchID, ComponentID =
>   @ComponentID       FROM       (          SELECT TOP (@BatchSize -
>   @RowsSelected) SeqID          FROM
>   TVF_MSSCrawlQueue_CrawlID_BatchID(@CrawlID, 0) _CrawlQueue_Tmp
>   OUTER APPLY TVF_MSSCrawlQueue_DocID_ComponentID(_CrawlQueue_Tmp.DocID,
>   @ComponentID) AS _CrawlQueue_DocID          --CROSS APPLY
>   TVF_MSSCrawlURL_DocID (_CrawlQueue_Tmp.DocID) _CrawlURL          WHERE
>   _CrawlQueue_DocID.DocID IS NULL              --AND _CrawlURL.DocID = xxxx          ORDER BY SeqID      ) AS _CrawlQueue_Top      CROSS
>   APPLY      TVF_MSSCrawlQueue_SeqID(_CrawlQueue_Top.SeqID) AS
>   _CrawlQueue      OPTION(FORCE ORDER, MAXDOP 1)  END  SELECT       _CrawlQueue.SeqID,      _CrawlQueue.SourceDocID,      _CrawlQueue.DocID,      _CrawlQueue.StartAddressID,      _CrawlQueue.HostDepth,      _CrawlQueue.EnumerationDepth,      _CrawlQueue.TransactionFlags | _CrawlURL.TransactionFlags,      _CrawlQueue.TransactionType,      _CrawlQueue.Scope,      _CrawlQueue.CachedBlob,      _CrawlURL.AccessURL,      _CrawlURL.CompactURL,      _CrawlURL.EndPathFlag,      _CrawlURL.MD5,      _CrawlURL.LastModifiedTime,      _CrawlURL.FolderDelCount,      _CrawlURL.ChangeLogCookie,      _CrawlURL.ChangeLogCookieType,      _CrawlURL.RetryCount,      _CrawlURL.HostID,      _CrawlURL.ParentHostID,      _CrawlURL.SecurityID,      _CrawlURL.PHFlags,      _CrawlURL.DelayRetryCount,      _CrawlURL.ChangeLogCookieEnd,      _CrawlURL.LogLevel,      _CrawlURL.IndexType,      _CrawlURL.SDHash,      _CrawlURL.PartitionID,      _CrawlQueue.MiniCrawlID,      DATEDIFF(millisecond, _CrawlQueue.TimeInsertedInLinksTable,
>   _CrawlQueue.TimeInsertedInQueue),      DATEDIFF(millisecond, _CrawlQueue.TimeInsertedInQueue, GetUTCDate() ),      _CrawlURL.ContentSourceID,      _CrawlURL.RefreshBucket,      _CrawlURL.RefreshPromoteCount,      _CrawlURL.SPOIndexTypeName  FROM TVF_MSSCrawlQueue_CrawlID_BatchID (@CrawlID, @BatchID) _CrawlQueue 
>   CROSS APPLY TVF_MSSCrawlURL_DocID(_CrawlQueue.DocID) _CrawlURL  ORDER
>   BY SeqID  OPTION(FORCE ORDER)  RETURN 1

Answer (score 0):

- Have you try to reduce the value @DocsInQueue < 1000000 ?
- Check the status of the mssdmn.exe process and see if it reach some kind of boundaries, cpu, memory, threads.
- Check the tables [MSSCrawlURLLog] and [MSSCrawlURL] and count the items every single url is a potential connection.
- Use wireshark Network tool and check if the connections are closed at network level use the filter **tcp.flags.fin eq 1 or tcp.flags.reset eq 1**, if the connection is not close then a timeout should pop out in the uls log.
- Recycling bits: This [blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sharepoint_strategery/2016/08/11/sp2013-crawling-explained-enumerationdiscovery-part-3b/) will explain in deep how the crawling occurs in the starting

These points will help you to pin down why are so many connections.
In some cases the crawler gets stuck in a document and rest of connections don't close properly until Search Service is stopped and restarted.

- Check that you can open the documents url via IE using crawler account and none firewall , Load balanced, nor proxy server stops the communication.